# Accessing a variable from a function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I need to access a variable which is inside a function from outside, ie. another function in the controller.

```
 public function method1()
 {
  $var=1;
 }

 public function method2()
 {
  $this->method1();
  //here i need to access the $var=1 from the method1()
 }
```

Comment: you can't. You could save $var1 in session, or if the two functions are called within the same controller instantiation, you can define it as a controller variable. Maybe if you explain why do you need this and how do you intend to use it, we can give a less vague answer.

Comment: I suggest you to study Php and OOP first..